# Content-Security-Policy refusing to load localhost script

Tags: content-security-policy, single-spa, import-maps

I'm building a micro-frontend web app with single-spa and am trying to set up import map overrides on my deployed site.

I'm getting the following console error when trying to load a micro frontend script from localhost

```
script-load.js:86 Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8085/whatever.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: localhost:*". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have the following `Content-Security-Policy` in my HTML:

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https: localhost:*; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: localhost:*; connect-src https: localhost:* ws://localhost:*; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https:; object-src 'none';"
```

I was under the impression that `script-src localhost:*` would allow overriding the MFE scripts with scripts I had running locally.

Comment: Isn't it because that the `script-src` directive as currently declared only allows for `https` but your script is served over `http`? This really has nothing to do with single-spa or import maps.

Comment: @filoxo yes localhost is served over `http` but the `script-src` section also contains `localhost:*` which as I understood it, should allow for localhost served scripts in addition to `https:`

Comment: That understanding is incorrect. Since no scheme is defined on that host source, only defined scheme sources will be allowed;`https:` being the only one defined.

Comment: @filoxo hmmm, thanks for telling me that. Do you have a potential solution? Either way, looks like I have some learning to do

Comment: A few ideas: allow `http:` scheme dynamically (assuming root-config renders using .ejs, you could interpolate a conditional `<% if (isLocal) { %> http:<% } %>` to enable for local; extend the idea to dev env if desired. Another option is to configure the dev servers to use https, which is doable without too much work but likely requires publishing/consuming shared configs. Last, omit that requirement from the CSP; not ideal but some orgs don't have that high of a security requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the import map like this don't add http before

```
 <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@dell/react1":"//localhost:8080/test-react1.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
```